# cp says it's removing files, but shouldn't be

Tags: backup, cp

Making a quick backup:

```
root@guilmon:/mnt/backup/guilmon/home# cp -uvfrx --preserve=all /home/rena/ .
```

The output is surprising - some files are said to be removed!

```
removed ‘./rena/dev/lua/conkybitcoin/conkybitcoin.lua’
```

The files being removed seem to be random and haven't changed. Why does it say it's removing them? Even stranger, it doesn't appear to have *actually* removed that file (nor the source). What's going on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`cp` with the `--force` and `--verbose` options (`-f` and `-v` in your command line) outputs the "removed" message whenever it removes a destination file before copying it. (`--force` tells `cp` to remove a destination file if it can't be opened, before trying the copy again.)

In your example, it means that `./rena/dev/lua/conkybitcoin/conkybitcoin.lua` couldn't be opened for writing, so `cp` removed it and copied it again from `/home/rena`.

Comment: I see. So then the question is why it couldn't be opened...

Comment: Is it read-only?

Comment: The real question is, ***was it*** (the pre-existing file in the destination directory) read-only before you ran the `cp` command?

Comment: Both are mode 0644, and I ran cp as root, so should be fine there. Existing destination should have been fine too since I used the same command to copy all of `/home` to the backup disk yesterday after creating a fresh, empty filesystem on it. `btrfs scrub` reports no errors on either disk.